# Changing data structure using convertAll

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a way to return a dynamic JSON to the the user. (Like in JavaScript you could simply add to the JSON, whatever you want)

I want to change a data structure to another data structure  I am using `convertAll`.

Please take a look here:

```
public dynamic SomeActionMethod()
{
    return Test_Get(). /* List<someClass> */
    ConvertAll(x =>
    {
        if (someConditionToCheckAgainst)
        {
            return new
            {
                subValue1 = x
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new
            {
                 subValue2 = x                     
            }
        {

    };
}
```

I get the following error:

> List.ConvertAll(Converter)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

What to do here?

Comment: Code in question not in image

Comment: You are right, i will change this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most flexible way to do this (see JObject, Json.Net serialization guides), but this can work for your example:

```
public class Item
{
    public int? month { get; set; }
    public int? total { get; set; }
}

var intList = new List<int> { 4, 12 };
var resultList = intList.ConvertAll(r =>
{
    if (r == 4)
    {
        return new Item { month = r };
    }
    else
    {
        return new Item { total = r };
    }
});

var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(intList, Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Note that `month` and `total` fields are nullable. Serializing with specified settings will not include null fields to result json.

Json will look like this: `[{ "month": 4 }, { "total": 12 }]`

Comment: I get `The type 'MyCustomClass' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'` and the result at the moment has always `subValue1` and `subValue2`, on the one time it is null and not null.

Comment: @user7425470 please show the code your trying to execute